# Can a virus scanner show there is virus but actually not?

Tags: anti-virus

I saw a specific program has this explanation for some of the virus scans showing it is a virus:

Virus scanner results: All virus scanner detection's are a false-positive as long as the MD5 matches. Simply turn off your anti-virus while installing this program.

Does it make sense? what does it mean by "as long as md5 matches"?

Answer (score 2):

Windows loaders are dodgy - they basically do the same kind of thing viruses do to convince windows its genuine. In this case it might be convincing the system it has some hardware it dosen't or even deeper, root-kit like behaviour.

In short, it *could* be a virus and the AV is working as is.

What they are telling you is "you can check to see the thing that may or may not be poison is exactly what we are saying it is" - an md5 sum is a unique-ish identifier of a file made by calculating a checksum, and is used to verify that a file isn't corrupted.

I'd also point out, a windows loader means you're pirating software, and there's an inherent legal and technical risk to it. Its your own fault if you get a virus since its the free candy van of software.

[image]

Comment: they calim that it is legal and it is just a hole that company M can never fix it with windows 7, what do u think?

Comment: I think if they claim its legal, their pants are on fire. Its clearly a lie, or they are deluded. You're pirating software, and using software thats similar enough to a virus to invariably trigger off a AV warning. Its the free candy van of software.

Comment: I have used a websites with like 50 different anti virus to check, around 20 out of 50 say it is virus while those other 30 say it is fine. Same thing happen for a program U use to cheat in a online game. For case like these then very likely ok? I expect a real virus would have almost all out of 50 saying it is virus.

Comment: It is true that if company M can bring this to court, I think company M would do it no.matter how much money it costs and shut down their website, and there is no way they can fight with company M no matter where do they host their website in the world.

Comment: I personally wouldn't take the risk, and just use legitimate software.

Comment: I guess if a program has virus, after running it then the antivirus should have high chance detect it is doing something abnormal in memory or internet outbound then immediately block it. Then within few says all anti virus software should notice that and mark it as serious virus. Since this program only update like once in half year but more than half of antivirus companies still consider it is safe, i guess it is actually safe but is this legal is another issue.

Comment: I think it comes down to "You want to be told its ok" I'm saying "No it isn't, and this is why". You're basically trying to convince yourself its safe despite knowing that something is odd. If you want to delude yourself, go ahead but *using cracked software is not a good idea*

Comment: i guess the antivirus companies mark it as virus either because their relationship with company M or they detect the program does use the step as a virus to do what it does.

Comment: I think it is as i just explain, it is possible to tell if it is 100% virus or it makes sense that a lot of antivirus companies dont consider it is virus because it is not. Legal or not is another ethnical question.

Answer (score 1):

Virus scanners can in fact have false positives, and blindly deleting everything it brings up isn't necessarily a good idea. If a program explicitly says it will trip off your virus scanner but is perfectly legitimate, there are two possibilities:

1. It is in fact an innocent program that just happens to clash with
   your antivirus, which happens
2. It's a trick to install a virus on your machine

"md5" refers to an md5 sum. It's something used to make sure a file was downloaded correctly or is actually the file it seems to be. There's probably an md5 sum wherever you downloaded the file that you can check against the program to verify it's valid. Basically the program is saying "This program is legitimate, unless somebody changed it to take advantage of the fact they knew people would need to shut off their virus scanners to use it, so check that this is the real deal". It's actually more commonly used just to make sure things didn't get corrupted during downloads.

EDIT: [The first random guide to checking an MD5 sum I found in my search](https://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/LQ_ISO/Checking_the_md5sum_in_Windows), if you're worried. If the sum you get from the application matches the one from the source and you're sure that the source is reputable, you're probably okay. Probably about 99% of the time this isn't actually necessary but it only takes a minute and it's a good practice.

EDIT: I'd just like to stress the "*you're sure that the source is reputable*" bit - if you got it off some shady site somewhere, it may well *be* a virus. Get it from the homepage or a link on the homepage if you can. If the group that created the file is shady, it may well be a virus.